# Win 10, 64 bit, dll problems

Tags: c++, dll, uwp

I have a UWP app with some c++ code that creates an Ip Camera and Server. I was getting the class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG) exception so I tried to use regsvr32.exe on the dll, but then I got that the module failed to load. So then I went to dependency walker and got errors that all of these were missing. I have all the redistributable c++ packages installed according to add/remove programs. How would I fix this?

```
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.



API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COMM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ENCLAVE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-INTERLOCKED-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NORMALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PERFCOUNTERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSSNAPSHOT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-ANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-APPCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-2-0.DLL
MSVCP140_APP.DLL
VCCORLIB140_APP.DLL
VCRUNTIME140_APP.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-3-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALREGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRINGANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-CONFIG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-QUERY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CLASSICPROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-UAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-SETTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSAPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NPUSERNAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NTMARTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-SAFER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DAXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOYONECORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-CONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-COM-PSMREGISTER-L1-2-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EDPUTIL-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EVENTING-RUNDOWN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-CLIPPING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-CREATE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRINT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-WCS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GPAPI-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MRMCORER-RESMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-EXTENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-LOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RPC-SSL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CHAMBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFSWRT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
```

Comment: You are chasing the wrong problem, this error is caused by your appx manifest missing the class you are trying to use.  In UWP it plays the same role as the registry used to play back in the olden days.  You of course left no clue whatsoever to guess why the manifest isn't being built correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant I was just following the breadcrumbs of what seemed to be giving me the problem. I don't have any clues to what would make the app manifest be missing that class. I am trying to port [this sample](https://github.com/mmaitre314/IpCamera) from 8.1 to UWP. I thought it would be simple since they are pretty closely related. What should I do to give more clues as to my actual issue. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I don't think so. Ended up going in a different direction for getting video off a hololens in near realtime. https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloLensCompanionKit/tree/master/MixedRemoteViewCompositor